# Set the line item value from a custom column using script #suitescript #Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to take the value from "custcol_po_cost" and put it into "porate".
I want this to happen when a quote is transformed into a sales order. This way the PO Rate can be stored in the quote. I am unsure where I have gone wrong, I am very new to this. I am also unsure of which Function I should use to make this happen.

```
function validateSOLineItem(type){
if(type == 'item'){
var amount = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_po_cost');
nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'porate', amount);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that returning an error?  Or just not doing anything?  Have you logged the value of amount, just to make sure it is grabbing the value from the field?

Comment: Are you transforming the qoute to SO from UI? If yes, should have page init function or beforeload to properly set the value on the column. When we are transforming transaction either via UI or suitescript, the values were only transferred and there is a need for customization. The function you are using right now will only work if the user will go through the line and enter it again.

Comment: It isn't returning an error. Yes I'm transforming the quote into a sales order via UI. I tried putting the function on pageinit and it didn't do anything. if I keep it on validate function It won't let my select ok on the line and save.

Answer (score 0):

If these fields are on both the sales order and quote form, they should automatically be transferred to the sales order when it is converted.  You need to add the function call to the event you want to trigger it.  I would guess either on source or after submit perhaps?  If you need to populate a field that is not on the original quote form you will need to do a user event.  Sorry, I might be misunderstanding what you are trying to do but if you can provide a little more detail I will sure try to help.

Comment: The PO Cost field is on both forms but the PO Rate is only on the sales order. I want to be able to put the purchase price into the PO Cost field on the quote and then when I transform the record into a sales order have it set the value of the PO Rate. I want this to be done on a line by line basis so the user doesn't have to re-enter the information.

Answer (score 0):

First off just from a teaching moment - validate line is a function built to identify any validation rules (data entry mistakes) and not allow the user to proceed until fixed. Because of this it returns a boolean of true/false to determine if the user can continue. The reason you can't click ok is because at no point does that return true.

That being said you should not use a validate line function. If this will forever be in the UI, with no chance of ever being from CSV or anything else, then you can use Client scripts or User Event. You can do Client side pageInit () or saveRecord () . In either of these you will want to do a for loop and iterate through your list to grab the value for each item.